# Blueprint CSS span-x in other classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, blueprint-css

In using blueprint css, I have several forms in my app - for example,

```
<div id="user_form" class"span-15">
  ---
</div>
```

If I want all of my forms to have that same span, can I do something like

```
<div id="user_form" class="form_conainer">
  ---
</div>
```

and apply that span-15 in my CSS file?  How would i do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id="user_form" class="form_conainer span-15">
```

How about doing like this?

Comment: that would work, but what I'm after is a uniform application of the span to the form_container -- If i want to change it for whatever reason, I'd like to do it in one place only.  Perhaps I wasn't clear in how I asked -- I'd like to include the span-x in my definition of the form_container class.

Comment: Sorry...  Ok, so let's say I have my form_container class - I can apply various styles to it, for example, I can set the text color to blue.  So all of my forms would have blue text, right?  later, I could go into my .css file & change it to red, and all of my forms would then have red text.  So what I'm looking for is a way to specify the column span inside the form_container definition along with those other attributes, so if I've got twenty forms in my app, each with class="span-15 push-1", and I want to change it to a span-20, I only have to do it in one place.  Does that make more sense?

Comment: I did a bit more searching, and what I want is "inheritance" which apparently, CSS does not do.  Thank you though, your suggestion was indeed helpful.